# Please help how to read an INI file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

This is an INI file:

```
[Generals]
gName=custumer
BackUp_Path=D:\backup\
User=User
Password=12345

[Group_1]
Name=2121
Item_name_1=R11
Item_var_1=111
Item_name_2=R13
Item_var_2=222
Item_name_3=R14
Item_var_3=333
Item_name_4=R15
Item_var_4=444
Item_name_5=R21
Item_var_5=555
Item_name_6=R23
Item_var_6=666

[Group_2]
Name=3331
Item_name_1=R11
Item_var_1=221
Item_name_2=R13
Item_var_2=321
Item_name_3=R14
Item_var_3=432
Item_name_4=R15
Item_var_4=434
Item_name_5=R21
Item_var_5=232
```

///////////////////////
My question is: Could someone help me to write a batch script that can read this INI file and loop through each group 1,2,3...and then pass each value to my own function.
for example 
gName is custumer
BackUp_Path is D:\backup\
Name is 2121
..........

```
:main

for /F ... do (
       call :functionA inifile gName BackUp_Path User Password Name Item_name_i Item_var_i
)


rem my own function 
:functionA 
    a1=%1
    a2= %2 
    a3= %3 
    a4= %4 
    a5= %5 
    a6= %6 
    a7= %7
    a8= %8
    a9= %9
    a10= %10
```

Can someone help this one why only work for the first loop:

```
@echo off
:main
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    set "inifile=C:\inifile.ini"

    set /a group_number=1
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('findstr /I "Group_" "%inifile%"') do(
        set "group_name=%%a" 
        echo The name of group_!group_number! is: !group_name!
        call :get-ini %inifile% %%a Name result3_!group_number!
        echo r3= !result3_%group_number%!
        set /a group_number=group_number+1
        echo group_number !group_number!
)
       echo ................
 :: The Batchography book by Elias Bachaalany
 :get-ini <filename> <section> <key> <result>

    set %~4=
    setlocal
    set insection=

    for /f "usebackq eol=; tokens=*" %%a in ("%~1") do (
        set line=%%a

        rem We are inside a section, look for the right key
        if defined insection (
            rem Let's look for the right key
            for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%b in ("!line!") do (
                if /i "%%b"=="%3" (
                    endlocal
                    set %~4=%%c
                    goto :eof
            )
        )
    )

        rem Is this a section?
        if "!line:~0,1!"=="[" (
            for /f "delims=[]" %%b in ("!line!") do (
                rem Is this the right section?
                if /i "%%b"=="%2" (
                   set insection=1
            ) else (
                rem We previously found the right section, so just exit when you encounter a new one
                endlocal
                if defined insection goto :eof
            )
        )
    )
)
    endlocal

pause
```

Comment: Read [ask] and `help for`.  We're not here to write code for you.  There are a many code-for-hire sites you can visit for that.

Comment: Additional research: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5Dini+file

Comment: yeah, thank, I tried by myself but i don't know how to assign the value in the INI file to the dynamic variable inside the for loop

Comment: You have to parse each line into varName and value variables, then use the varName for value as a variable name.  `set "%varName%=%value%"`.  Read `help for`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a commented batch script demonstrating how the data in the INI file could be processed by a batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "%~dp0Test.ini" goto EndBatch
set "Group="

rem Process each non-empty line and each line not starting with a semicolon.
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%~dp0Test.ini") do (
    rem Split up each line into up two substrings with using equal sign,
    rem underscore and closing square bracket as string delimiters.
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==_]" %%J in ("%%~I") do (
        rem Is the first string case-insensitive the string "[Group"?
        if /I "%%J" == "[Group" (
            rem Was before a group already processed? Yes, output the data.
            if defined Group call :OutputGroupData
            rem Setup environment variables for new group.
            rem Store group number.
            set "Group=%%K"
            rem Remove all Item environment variables of previous group.
            for /F "delims==" %%V in ('set Item_ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="
            rem Reset item count to 0.
            set "ItemCount=0"
            rem Initialize the environment variable Name.
            set "Name=none"
        ) else if /I "%%J" == "Item" (
            rem This line contains an item entry.
            set "%%I"
            rem Count the items on lines starting with Item_name.
            if /I "%%K" == "name" set /A ItemCount+=1
        ) else if /I "%%J" == "Name" set "%%I"
    )
)
rem Output also the data of last group.
if defined Group call :OutputGroupData
goto EndBatch

:OutputGroupData
echo(
if %ItemCount% == 0 (
   echo Group %Group% with name "%Name%" has no items.
) else if %ItemCount% == 1 (
   echo Group %Group% with name "%Name%" has 1 item:
   echo(
   set Item_
) else (
   echo Group %Group% with name "%Name%" has %ItemCount% items:
   echo(
   set Item_
)
rem Return to command line below calling subroutine OutputGroupData.
goto :EOF

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `set` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between `'` appended as further arguments.